# Add storage to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to add storage to an EC2 instance? The default set up I have has 30GB of memory and I'd like 100 on it.

I [created an AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html) from the instance but doesn't seem like you can attach it?

How can I add storage to running EC2 instance?

Comment: Are you referring to **disk storage** or **memory/RAM**?

Comment: to up your storage check this detailed guide https://devscover.com/aws/extend-your-ec2-storage-volume-size/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some clarification...

The word "storage" is traditionally used for **disk storage**. Try to avoid using the word "storage" when referring to **memory/RAM**.

If you wish to change the **memory** assigned to an Amazon EC2 instance:

- **Stop** the instance
- Change the [Instance Type](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)
- **Start** the instance

Behind-the-scenes, the instance will be allocated to a different type of host computer that has a different amount of CPU, RAM, Networking, etc. This is why the instance must be stopped, changed, and started.

If you are actually referring to **disk storage**, then there are two options to increase the storage:

- **Modify** the Amazon EBS volume and increase the storage space, then tell your operating system to extend the disk onto the larger disk, *OR*
- Create an **additional Amazon EBS volume** and attach it to the Amazon EC2 instance (which will create an additional disk device)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to modify volume.
Identify the EBS Volume of your EC2 instance.
Or check in the description of ec2 instance.
You will find the vol-id there.

Go to that volume --> In Actions --> modify volume.